# datagride Mvvm update and insert from external fields

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have data grid that I want to update from external fields
I don't want to directly affect the data base

```
 <DataGrid
                    AlternatingRowBackground="CadetBlue "
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Addresss ,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Address, Mode=OneWayToSource}"

                    ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterColumnHeader}"
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridContentCellCentering}">
                    
                    <DataGrid.Columns>

                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            
                            Width="70"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=AddType}"
                            Header="النوع" 
                           
                                    /> 

                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Width="80"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=AddAdjective}"
                            Header="الوصف" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn
                            Width="250"
                            Binding="{Binding Path=AddAddress}"
                            Header="العنوان" />


                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I made a combo box

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Cbox1" Width="69"
                        materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="النوع"
                        Background="#252525"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddTypelist}"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Addressl.AddType}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBoxFocus}" 
                        IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="True"/>
```

I don't want the change to happen automatically. When I change it in the combo box, I want the process to be done with a button
I tried this method

```
 public AddressTable Address
        {
            get =>  _address;
            set
            {
                _address = value;
                _addressl = _address;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Address);
               
            }
        }
        private AddressTable _addressl;

        public AddressTable Addressl
        {
            get =>  _addressl;
            set
            {
                _addressl = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Addressl);
            }
        }
```

But it didn't work

Comment: The combobox is outside the datagrid?  I don't follow what you intend doing with it and you missed out what addtypelist. Please add sufficient code and markup that someone can reproduce your issue. Please also clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: At the moment you seem to have a property Addresss which is presumably a collection of addresses. I recommend you change that name so it's clearer. At first glance it looks like you're binding itemssource and selecteditem to the same property.